# Vue Test Utils with Vitest: AssertionError for $routerMock.push in unit test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, mocking, router, vitest

I'm facing an issue with my unit test for a Vue.js component using Vue Test Utils and Vitest. I have a component named TheFooter.vue, and I'm trying to test whether clicking on a link triggers navigation to the correct route. However, I'm encountering an AssertionError with the message:
`AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: []expected "spy" to be called with arguments:`

`TheFooter.vue`

```
    <template>
      <footer class="footer">
         <ul class="footer-links">
           <li
             v-for="link in footerLinks"
            :key="link"
          >
            <RouterLink
              data-test="footer-link"
              class="fw500-ar font-dark-L40-D50 footer-link"
              :to="{ name: link.link }"
            >
              {{ link.title }}
            </RouterLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </template>

    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { computed } from "vue";
    import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

    const { tm } = useI18n({ useScope: "global" });
    const footerLinks = computed(() => {
      return tm("footerLinks");
    });
    </script>
```

`TheFooter.spec.ts`

```
import { flushPromises, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { afterEach, beforeEach, describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest";
import { i18n } from "@/plugins/localization/localization";
import TheFooter from "@/components/layout/TheFooter.vue";

vi.mock("vue-router");

describe("TheFooter.vue unit test", () => {
  const $routerMock = {
    push: vi.fn(),
  };

  let wrapper = shallowMount(TheFooter, {
    global: {
      plugins: [i18n],
      stubs: ["RouterLink"],
      mocks: {
        $router: $routerMock,
      },
    },
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    $routerMock.push.mockReset();
    wrapper = shallowMount(TheFooter, {
      global: {
        plugins: [i18n],
        stubs: ["RouterLink"],
        mocks: {
          $router: $routerMock,
        },
      },
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  it("navigates to the correct route when a link is clicked", async () => {
    // Access all links using the data-test attribute
    const links = wrapper.find('[data-test="footer-link"]');
    console.log("links", links.exists());
    // Access the keys of the footerLinks object
    // const linkKeys = Object.keys(wrapper.vm.footerLinks);

    // Assert that the correct number of links is rendered
    // expect(links).toHaveLength(linkKeys.length);
    await flushPromises();
    // Simulate a click on the first link
    await links.trigger("click");

    // expect that navigation happened
    expect($routerMock.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });
});
```

I expected the unit test to pass, indicating that clicking on a link in TheFooter.vue correctly triggers navigation to the specified route.
I would sincerely appreciate any guidance or insights the community can provide in resolving this issue. If anyone has experience with Vue Test Utils and ViTest, your expertise would be invaluable.

Comment: You stubbed RouterLink and it's not expected to do anything

Comment: I stubbed RouterLink to fix: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: RouterLink

Comment: You either need to register router plugin the usual way, so it would register router comps, which may have other undesirable effects, or mock RouterLink to the point it fits your expectations, i.e. calls $router.push on click